# Shouldn't I be able to offer a bounty of 100 on this question?

Tags: support

I have this [one issue which has been driving me crazy for ages](https://askubuntu.com/q/122148/17041). However, with help from Ask Ubuntu, I feel it's closing in on a solution. I've discovered a workaround, and maybe that can be exploited to find an answer. Thus I was hoping maybe I could push to the finish line by offering a bounty.

I previously offered a bounty of 50 points, so this would be the second bounty. My understanding is that if I offer a second bounty, I would have to offer at least double the previous amount. My expectation, then, was that I would have to offer a minimum bounty of 100 points.

However, when I was considering the bounty and clicked the "start a bounty" link I noticed that the minimum bounty it would allow me to set was 200. It would be worth 200 points to me, but since I only have 215 points, that would wipe me out. (I don't really care so much about building "rep" as I do about being able to participate in a marketplace of helpfulness).

Why is it only giving me the option of 200? Is there some other factor that is preventing me from offering 100? I thought maybe I offered two bounties and forgot, but if that were the case, then shouldn't two of the answers be marked as having had bounties? I can only see the one for 50 points.

I've read through the FAQs and other questions, and I can't see any clear reason why 200 is the minimum in this case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are mostly correct except that the previous bounty was 100 rep.

See the post's revisions:

- https://askubuntu.com/posts/122148/revisions

Comment: So I offered a bounty of 100? Oh... wait... I get it now. It must have gone past the due date and half was awarded automatically. I totally forgot about that. Good tip to know that the bounty information is stored in the question revisions. I wasn't aware of that.